# Regarding creating a virtual drive using subst

Tags: windows, batch-file

What is the significance of creating virtual drive in windows using subst command.
I am creating virtual drive to my original source code directory and then using virtual drive for everything like compilation, editing etc.

What is the main use of that ? Can't we work on the original directory where I have made the checkout of the source code ?

Comment: It depends. For example your tool chain can have restrictions  for paths - does not support long file names (times of MS DOS) or does not support paths, longer than 260 symbols (times of windows 95). Generally for modern tools it is not needed

Comment: MSdos 1 didn't do directories. Subst allowed Dos 1 programs to work on Dos 2 and later (by pretending a directory was a drive). People found it useful so the feature hangs about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(collected all the comments up to now to a community answer, as they are all good and up to the point and together build a good answer. Feel free to add more information. - *Stephan*)

It depends. For example your tool chain can have restrictions for paths - does not support long file names (times of MS DOS) or does not support paths, longer than 260 symbols (times of windows 95). Generally for modern tools it is not needed – *vitalygolub*

When multiple developers work on a project and the developers don't have all the same directory structure above the project directory with the sources, it makes often sense to substitute the project's parent directory as drive. Then all developers can work with the project with absolute paths although the project is stored in different directories on the machines of the developers. – *Mofi*

Also some compilers like Visual C/C++ compile even into release executable under some conditions absolute source paths. I have seen already many `User\user name\...` or `User/user name/...` in many `*.exe` and `*.dll` files. It is sometimes really interesting to see the name of the user account of a developer in an executable or library. The usage of a directory substituted to a drive helps to avoid making user account names unintentionally public like having projects not stored in a subdirectory of `%USERPROFILE%`. – *Mofi*

Another reason is often debugging with absolute paths in the files. Relative paths are sometimes problematic as the debugger needs to know which directory the paths are relative. The usage of (shorter) absolute paths in the files because of using project directory as virtual drive avoids issues caused by paths relative to wrong directory on debugging. – *Mofi*

MSdos 1 didn't do directories. Subst allowed Dos 1 programs to work on Dos 2 and later (by pretending a directory was a drive). People found it useful so the feature hangs about. – *Noodles*